# want to show and hide text using "this" jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to achieve this effect with `this` because I have several paragraphs like this so I don't wanna use id for each paragraph

```
<p class="desc_services_subheading">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    <span class="click" style="display:none;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    </span>
</p>
<p class="text-center">
   <button class="btn btn-default serivce-button clickme">
       More
   </button>
</p>
```

My JS

```
$('.clickme').click(function(){
    $('.click').toggle("200");
});
```

My attempt:

```
$('.clickme').click(function(){
    $('.click', this).toggle("200");
});
```

Comment: "this" effect is not linked to anything.

Comment: where is `click` class

Comment: How are you planning to show it again?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess OP wants to link the button `more` with corresponding `click span class`

```
$('.clickme').click(function(){

  $(this).parent().prev().find(".click").toggle();
 });
```

[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3a21ono9/)